# max and min values on symmetric polytope

Tags: geometry, optimization, convex-optimization, polytopes

Let $-N\leq t \leq N$.

Let $A$ be regular $(N-1)$-dimensional simplex with vertices $(t,0, \ldots, 0)\ldots (0, 0,\ldots, t)$ and $B$  be regular $(N-1)$-dimensional simplex with vertices $(t-N+1,1, \ldots, 1)\ldots (1,1, \ldots, t-N+1)$.

The intersection $A \cap B=P(N, t)$ is a polytope with $N {N-1 \choose m}$ vertices, where $m<t<m+1, \, 0<m<N, \, m \in N$. These $N {N-1 \choose m}$ vertices have $m$ coordinates $1$, $N-m-1$ coordinates $0$ and $1$ coordinate $t-m$.

Polytope  polytope $P(N,t)$ can be subdivide into $N {N-1 \choose m}$  equal parts,$Q_v$, such that each part would correspond to one vertex of $P(N,t)$. (see [Splitting polytope into equal parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715111/splitting-polytope-into-equal-parts))

Let $f$ be some function defined on $P(N,t)$.

**Question:** Where the maximum and the minimum
 values of $f$ on $Q_v$ would be attained?

Comment: What do you know about $f$?

Comment: I know that $f$ is a $p$-norm of some sum, say, e.x. $f=|\sum_i x_I\epsilon_i|^p$, where $\epsilon$ are Bernoulli random variables.