# building a polytop from polytop and finding its volume

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, polytopes

Let $P$ be a symmetric polytope with $M$ vertices. Suppose we subdivide this polytope into $M$ equal parts $A_i, i=1, \ldots, M$ such that each part $A_i$ correspond to one vertex, $v_i, i=1, \ldots, M$ of the $P$ ( see e.x. [Splitting polytope into equal parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715111/splitting-polytope-into-equal-parts)).

Consider one part $A_i$. $A_i$ is a symmetric polytope congruent to $P$.

1. How to build up a new polytope $B_i$ from $A_i$ in a way that the vertex $v_i$ would be a centroid of this new polytope $B_i$?
2. What is the volume of $B_i$?

Comment: Note that in my answer to the linked question, the polytopes $A_i$ at each vertex aren't similar to the original polytope $P$ (of course it's impossible that they would be congruent to $P$), and they don't necessarily have any symmetry properties (saying "symmetric polytope" is really vague, though.)